# It is possible to easily convert ycbcr to rgb before sending to hdmi output in android/linux?

Tags: android, rgb, hdmi, dvi

MK802 android mini pc screen has pink tint/doesnt work, when using with DVI monitor through HDMI-DVI cable, probably because it is outputing YCbCr HDMI signal, altrough DVI supports only RGB.

My question is if it is possible to convert this signal to RGB before outputing through hdmi and if yes, in which source file of android/cyanogenmod? I dont have android programming experiencies, but I think it could be easy to change it and build it afterwards, when I would know that it is possible somewhere. (I can programm in C and Cpp a bit)

Or there is also more linux distributions that MK802 runs, so maybe it is possible to change it somewhere in X server?

Answer (score 3):

I have an iStick from a company PQ Labs Inc https://store.pqlabs.com/

It uses:

- Processor: ARM V8 / 1GHz
- GPU: MALI 400

I am using a Fujitsu Plasmavision W 50 inch which I bought in the early 2000's Has one DVI input the designer thought ahead it is a DVI-D with HDCP support.

I have no offset problem But the magenta color issue is.

Will condense this next part about HDMI. HDMI Cable is

- Type A Connector 19pin
- Type B 29pin not part of this
- Type C

A Mini connector defined in the HDMI 1.3 specification, it is intended for portable devices.[1][102][103] It is smaller than the type A plug connector (10.42 mm × 2.42 mm) but has the same 19-pin configuration.[102][104] The differences are that all positive signals of the differential pairs are swapped with their corresponding shield, the DDC/CEC Ground is assigned to pin 13 instead of pin 17, the CEC is assigned to pin 14 instead of pin 13, and the reserved pin is 17 instead of pin 14.[105] The type C Mini connector can be connected to a type A connector using a type A-to-type C cable.

Note the wiring

By the way I figured out a way to make it work that cost about $30.00

I took one of the 1x2 splitter switch units that I had bought from www.monoprice.com and ran from my iStick to it and HDMI cable to a HDMI-DIV adapter plug .

If I use a GE 2-device switch (it is mechanical type switcher) the magenta is present.
The monoprice having the amplifier Isolates what might be a C type to A type problem.

A guess would be the output plug was wired when designing was done with the wiring of the C type which if store bought are pin to pin straight wired IE 1-1, 2-2 etc
would this be the problem just buy a cheap but good amplified splitter till your DVI device dies